# Where do the codes reside when I install a ROS package using apt?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recently installed turtlebot3 packages on my system using the apt package manager. But when I go into the package 'turtlebot3_teleop' I dont see any codes or anything. I just see a folder called 'launch' supposedly where all the launch files reside and a cmake file. I wanted to know where are the codes which make the turtlebot3  subscribe to the values I publish through my keyboard keys? Also where are the codes for the nodes which run when I run the launch file?

I have some idea that these packages are installed as binary packages, hence only their executable form is visible, but I don't have much clarity about this.

Pls explain

TIA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345599/where-do-the-codes-reside-when-i-install-a-ros-package-using-apt?/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2020-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-02**:
This seems like a duplicate of #q246775 and #q295677.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no code when you install using apt. Those are precompiled binaries that get installed under `/opt/ros/melodic/`

Launch files are in `/opt/ros/melodic/share/pkg_name/`

Python code might also be there, look in `/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_name/`

Best is to clone the repositories you need from github and compile them by yourself in a catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2020-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-02**:
+100 for answering, but if possible, search for duplicates first (use Google: `search terms site:answers.ros.org`).